# Steps to keep in mind while replacing existing android app

Tags: android

I have published an app which is at version 3.0. I have made some changes to the app now and want to upload newer version that is 4.0. How can i do that in android market? What steps i need to keep in mind or be aware of before doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html) should provide you with the information you need on versioning your android applications.